# Stored procedure LIKE Operation for parameters

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have an Excel where I am connecting to my stored procedure using Microsoft Query.

My procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WatchDogDataCollector] 
    @websiteID int = NULL, 
    @FailureLogStart datetime = NULL, 
    @FailureLogEnd datetime = NULL
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
    WHERE websiteID  = ISNULL(@websiteID,websiteID)
      AND (((FailureLogStart LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@FailureLogStart, FailureLogStart) + '%'))) 
      AND (((FailureLogEnd LIKE  '%' + ISNULL(@FailureLogEnd, @FailureLogEnd) + '%')))
```

My goal is to have the datetime columns `FailureLogStart` & `FailureLogEnd` 
to be have as a like that are optional.

So far so good once connected with Excel and I am trying to run my stored procedure with some dynamic parameters I get an error message:

> [Microsfot][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Conversion failed when
>   converting date and / or time from charter string

I am not sure If I am doing something wrong in Excel or in SQL?

Comment: I'm guessing `FailureLogStart` and `FailureLogEnd` are datetime, not strings, hence your exception. What is your goal in this query? add some sample data and desired results so that we can come up with a query that works.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Well at the end the user has some textboxes in excel and he can filter the table depending  on the input for example if he types in 2016 get all from data containing 2016

Comment: Well, in that case, you can cast the datetime to strings, but your parameters are of type datetime, so I'm guessing that if the user only enters `2016` the procedure will fail when attempting to convert `2016` to a valid datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the error message and the query, i think there should be datatype mismatch because like operator is an alphanumeric filter i.e. it takes string type. So, this should work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WatchDogDataCollector] 
    @websiteID int = NULL, 
    @FailureLogStart datetime = NULL, 
    @FailureLogEnd datetime = NULL
AS 
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
WHERE 
    websiteID  = ISNULL(@websiteID,websiteID)
    AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), FailureLogStart) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), ISNULL(@FailureLogStart, FailureLogStart)) + '%'))) 
    AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), FailureLogEnd) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), ISNULL(@FailureLogEnd, FailureLogEnd)) + '%')))
```

But this has an overhead of converting the datetime column data to nvarchar.

Instead, you can also format the datatime data to int type and then compare.
eg. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), GETDATE(), 112).
which will be some efficient then string search if index is also created.

Like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WatchDogDataCollector] 
    @websiteID int = NULL, 
    @FailureLogStart nvarchar(40) = NULL, -- datetime Changed to allow "2016" in search text box.
    @FailureLogEnd nvarchar(40) = NULL -- datetime
AS   

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
WHERE 
    websiteID  = ISNULL(@websiteID,websiteID)
    AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(35), FailureLogStart, 112) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(35), ISNULL(@FailureLogStart, FailureLogStart), 112) + '%'))) 
    AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(35), FailureLogEnd, 112) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(35), ISNULL(@FailureLogEnd, FailureLogEnd), 112) + '%')))
```

Comment: thanks allot for your time ! but I still have the same issue Conversion failed when converting date and / or time from charter string

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer for like predicate it should be string type. So, in the answer for the not null case it was not converted into string type which I have corrected now. And I have also added an another sample for you. You can try that also. Thanks for adding comment.

Comment: One more time thank you so much but no I get the message that the input is vaild date time

Comment: That is fine, it means now you need to check for valid date in your records, which you can do by using IsDate Function as eg. "AND Isdate([FailureLogStart]) = 1 AND Isdate([FailureLogEnd]) = 1 " in your query. This function will return 0 if dattime data is not a valid date.

Comment: Also keep in mind @Zohar Peled's last comment. There should be a valid datetime passed to the SP parameters (Same datetime format as in your table record(s)).

Comment: well idk if that is fine since it should work like a 'LIKE' so ofc when I type 2016 I would like to get all the results containing 2016  ? BTW in the db the enteries are saved like that 2016-05-08 09:57:03.323

Comment: In that case, you can change datetime SP parameters to nvarchar(40) and you are done. It will work as you want.

Comment: So what I did now is that I maid a query loocking like that  'WHERE websiteID = 17 AND (((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40), FailureLogStart, 112) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40),2016-01, 112) + '%')))' even doe there should be a output, my output from the query is empty

Comment: No no, not like that. I have updated my answer for you. Please refer after "Like:" portion in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters as varchars are they are not full dates:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WatchDogDataCollector] @websiteID int = NULL, @FailureLogStart datetime = NULL, @FailureLogEnd datetime = NULL
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM WATCHDOG.WatchdogUsr.WebsiteFailureLog
WHERE websiteID  = ISNULL(@websiteID,websiteID)
AND (((cast(FailureLogStart as varchar(50)) like '%'+ISNULL(@FailureLogStart, cast(FailureLogStart as varchar(50)))+'%'))) 
AND (((cast(FailureLogEnd as varchar(50)) like '%'+ISNULL(@FailureLogEnd, cast(FailureLogEnd as varchar(50)))+'%')))
```

Comment: Well but I have to since I can not expcet the user to know the exact datetime

Comment: @Niko.K I have changed the code so partial dates can be compared.

Comment: thanks allot for your time ! but I still have the same issue Conversion failed when converting date and / or time from charter string

Comment: @Niko.K I understand. Code changed again.

Comment: One more time thank you so much but no I get the message that the input is vaild date time

Comment: @Niko.K Can you supply the parameters you are passing?

Comment: This is how it saved in the db for example 2016-01-24 11:28:22.233 and I am sending a 2016-01 but what I tested in the query editor if I send the input like this '2017/01' it works fine and gives back results

Comment: @Niko.K In that case, pass the parameters as varchars. Code amended.

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index

Comment: @Niko.K Change Microsoft Query to pass as varchars.

Comment: how would this look like '